# Make init script output available without hitting the filesystem

Tags: socket, init.d, gentoo, stdout, named-pipes

I'm working on an init script for a command which writes extensive activity messages to stdout.

The output is only useful for debugging and since it will be running on a Pi, I don't want these messages be written to the filesystem.

Is it possible to forward the output to a named pipe, socket or something where it can be read from if needed, but if it's not read, the data is just discarded without hitting the filesystem?

Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 0):

Both Named pipes and netcat come with serious downsides, so I've decided to create an ebuild for procServ which works like a charm on my little Odroid (arm). The ebuild "net-misc/procserv" is on my overlay:

https://github.com/svoop/bitcetera-overlay